# “Uncaught ReferenceError: cordova is not defined”

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I'm trying use the Facebook slider menu on iOS, with the PhoneGap. The problem is that I am not able to insert data in sqlite, When clicking on the save button I got this error:

`"Uncaught ReferenceError: cordova is not defined".`

This is the source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Registration Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/index.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/SQLitePlugin.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        // Wait for Cordova to load
    //
   document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

   function onDeviceReady() {
     console.log("device ready");
   }

   function insert() {
   console.log("Run1");
   var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({
     name: "PHR.db"
   });
   db.transaction(function(tx) {
     tx.executeSql(
       'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SignUp (firstname VARCHAR,lastname VARCHAR,email VARCHAR, password VARCHAR ,question1 VARCHAR, answer1 VARCHAR,question2 VARCHAR,answer2 VARCHAR, question3 VARCHAR,answer3 VARCHAR)'
     );
   });
   db.transaction(function(tx) {
     var fname = document.getElementById("fn").value;
     var lname = document.getElementById("ln").value;
     var emai = document.getElementById("em").value;
     var passw = document.getElementById("pas").value;
     var qus1 = document.getElementById("qs1").value;
     var ans1 = document.getElementById("as1").value;
     var qus2 = document.getElementById("qs2").value;
     var ans2 = document.getElementById("as2").value;
     var qus3 = document.getElementById("qs3").value;
     var ans3 = document.getElementById("as3").value;
     tx.executeSql(
       'INSERT INTO SignUp (firstname,lastname,email, password ,question1 , answer1 ,question2 ,answer2 , question3,answer3) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', [
         fname, lname, emai, passw, qus1, ans1, qus2, ans2, qus3,
         ans3
       ]);
   }, null);
   });
   }    

    </script>
```

Comment: Your missed the Cordova  part to define...

Comment: Did you forget to invlude cordova.js?

Comment: Did you ever get solution for this?

Answer (score 5):

you need to add

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

in the head tag

Answer (score 1):

In your code :

```
<head>
<title>Registration Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/index.css" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>  //--> You missed this line.
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/SQLitePlugin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
//Remaining code goes here ... ...
```

Answer (score 0):

add the cordova script in your html file, int he head

Answer (score 0):

I was in a very tricky situation with reactjs + cordova for mobile. This was specifically happening when trying to leverage cordova's datadirectory field on a mobile device, the prod build would error out.

The solution that worked for me

## Simply reference `window.cordova` instead of `cordova`